# How to use the epoll/kqueue enabled version of GHC/Haskell for network connections?

Tags: haskell, ghc, epoll

There is a lot of old information on the net regarding an epoll/kqueue enabled GHC. For example, the code on the [Simple Servers wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_Servers) doesn't compile anymore.

Could someone provide a basic example of how to use this feature with a modern GHC version to build, e.g. a TCP server that just responds with "Hello" on connect?

Comment: Can you describe what "doesn't compile any more" means, and include the code you're trying to compile directly in your question here? (As evidence that I'm not just trying to enforce arbitrary rules: I stuck the code from the section titled "Basic concurrent server" in a file, and it compiled fine on my machine. So further details on what you're trying to do are really necessary.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Hi Daniel. Sure. If you look at the last example, the one that actually uses `epoll`, it makes use of a `loop` function but that isn't even in the example. I get the error `app3/Main.hs:14:5: Not in scope: ‘loop’`. That's after I changed `System.Event` to `GHC.Event` which is not noted anywhere.

Comment: The wiki page is out of date. GHC's IO manager uses epoll/kqueue under the hood without any special programmer effort (and [has for five years](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/635)). So just write the naive threaded version at the top of the page.

Comment: @DanielWagner I just wanted to be clear. The `forkIO` example with an `accept` call in each thread, uses epoll/kqueue under the hood already? Cool.

Comment: Yes, the `forkIO` example with a `body` call in each thread will use epoll/kqueue.

Comment: @DanielWagner looks like you've answered this question with your comment starting "The wiki page is out of date". You might want to plonk it in as the answer so that this question is complete.

Comment: @StevenShaw Done.

Answer (score 2):

GHC's IO manager uses epoll/kqueue under the hood without any special programmer effort. Just write the naive threaded program -- that puts each concurrent blocking IO call in a separate thread -- and GHC will make sure it works out the way you want it to.