# Why does haskell's network library use non-blocking sockets?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to better understand a design decision made in the [network](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network) library. Reputable sources mention in [a github issue](https://github.com/haskell/network/issues/151#issuecomment-65463634) and a [mailing list response](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-August/082727.html) that `network` uses non-blocking sockets. Instead of using the default blocking behavior, they use [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to block until the socket is ready to be read. Why is this better? Either way, it ends up blocking, and `network` only exposes a blocking API to end users. My guess is that it's bad for an FFI call to block and that there is some kind of GHC magic around `select`, but I haven't been able to confirm that.

As a minor aside, I cannot find where `select` in called in `network`. Grepping the codebase did not turn up anything. I just discovered [GHC.Event](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Event.html), which seems to provide functions that would be used instead of calling `select` directly, but grepping shows `network` doesn't use this either.

Comment: There should be a select (or poll) loop somewhere in the ghc runtime system. In general, ghc tries to use non-blocking I/O everywhere.

Comment: I'd _guess_ that this is used as a 'yield' point for GHCs green thread scheduler to (possibly) give control to another thread? Don't really know either though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The non-blocking IO event loop is part of GHC's runtime system (RTS). This interacts very nicely with GHC's green thread system: instead of writing asynchronous code, you can just use lightweight threads and the runtime will take care of waking up the correct one.

All IO in in Haskell is non-blocking by default, so if you've got two threads that are each blocked on a different socket, then the runtime system will internally do `select` (or some other platform-specific way to wait on multiple file descriptors like `epoll` or `kqueue`) to only wake the thread up when the file descriptor becomes ready. See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/IOManager for more details.

Comment: Wouldn't it better fit that model if `network` relied on `epoll` instead of `select`?

Comment: It might be that it acutally uses `epoll` on linux, I belive that is the case.

@sapanoia see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39106000/2494803